# How do I select multiple text tags and assign different values to them?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an array with 38 different strings that I want to add to 38 different  tags, every time I try to do that, I end up selecting only the first  tag because it doesn't understand that I want to loop through the  tags too, the text tags are all similar to each with only a minor difference in their y value. Below is an example of one of two  tags.

```
<text x="33" y="13" fill="black" style="font-size:70%"></text>
<circle cx="20" cy="30" r="6" fill="#ede847"  stroke="black"/>
<text x="33" y="33" fill="black" style="font-size:70%"></text>
```

This is the script I'm using to add the text I want

```
var lines = ["1:","2:"]
var stations = ["Finch","North York Centre","Sheppard-Yonge","York Mills","Lawrence","Eglinton","Davisville","St Clair","Summerhill","Rosedale","Bloor-Yonge","Wellesley","College","Dundas","Queen","King","Union","St Andrew","Osgoode","St Patrick","Queen's Park","Museum","St George","Spadina","Dupont","St Clair West","Eglinton West","Glencairn","Lawrence West","Yorkdale","Wilson","Sheppard West","Downsview Park","Finch West","York University","Pioneer Village","Highway 407","Vaughan Metropolitan Centre"]
var closure_type = ["nightly early closures","single day closure","weekend closure"]

stations.forEach(function(station, index) {

    currentEl = d3.selectAll("text")[0][index];
    currentEl.innerHTML = station;

  });
```

Can you please let me know what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all the elements use `selectAll` and then use the index value to access each of them. Below is an example with two elements from array:

```js
var stations = ["Finch","North York Centre"]

stations.forEach(function(station, index) {

    currentEl = d3.selectAll("text")[0][index];
    currentEl.innerHTML = station;
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.0.2/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="300">
<text x="33" y="13" fill="black" style="font-size:70%"></text>
<circle cx="20" cy="30" r="6" fill="#ede847"  stroke="black"/>
<text x="33" y="33" fill="black" style="font-size:70%"></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: why, how can i help you more ? Is not the answer according to question ?

Comment: But you can run the code snippit given by me in my answer and its working. Can  you create jsfiddle of your code and share here ?

Comment: I just noticed that. However it's not working when I use it in VScode.

Comment: Can you please share your code here, just edit your question and write all snippit ? Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209606/discussion-between-prince-and-khaledcodes).

Comment: 2 errors, VM130 app.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    at VM130 app.js:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM130 app.js:5
(anonymous) @ VM130 app.js:7
(anonymous) @ VM130 app.js:5
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map
app.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at VM130 app.js:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM130 app.js:5